# VBA Access DMAX invoice number criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to add an invoice number through using DMAX function to populate a textbox with the next consecutive invoice number. Depending on the estate agents name chosen in the combobox Me.cmb_CustomerType.Value, the invoice number (Survey_InvoiceNumber, Survey_tbl) will start with a different number e.g. Elmhurst will start with 08, Bridgfords will start with 05 and Harringtons durham will start with 04. 
I've tried using select statements, left, dmax, dlookup from various forums but can't get it to work and i'm at my wits end with it!

```
If cmb_CustomerType.Value = "Elmhurst" Then
Me.txt_InvoiceNumber.Value = DMax("Survey_InvoiceNumber", "Survey_tbl", "08") + 1
End If

If cmb_CustomerType.Value = "Bridgfords" Then
    Me.txt_InvoiceNumber = Nz(DMax("Survey_InvoiceNumber", "Survey_tbl", "05") + 1)
End If

If cmb_CustomerType.Value = "Harringtons Durham" Then
    Me.txt_InvoiceNumber = Nz(DMax("Survey_InvoiceNumber", "Survey_tbl", "04") + 1)
End If
```

It's only returning '8884' for all of the estate agents as that is the highest number in that column.

Results should be: Elmhurst - 08884, Harringtons Durham - 04048

There's currently no value in for bridgfords, therefore it should start with 05000.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: First, is your Survey_InvoiceNumber" column a string or a long? If you really want a leading zero (08..,05...,04...) its better to make a string, however it looks like a long as your dmax returns 8884 (no leading zero). Then, do you have a column storing the customer type, or do you rely only on the first digit of your invoice number to determine it (bad idea) ?

Comment: @Thomas G,  I've got an attribute for the 'Customer_Type' which is stored in 'Customer_tbl'. I made the Survey_InvoiceNumber column short text to allow the number to start with 0, but it doesn't seem to have any affect in the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this skeleton:

```
Me.txt_InvoiceNumber.Value = "08" & Right(Format(Val(Nz(DMax("Survey_InvoiceNumber", "Survey_tbl", "Survey_InvoiceNumber Like '08*'")) + 1), "00000"), 3)
```